# How to select a date interval

Tags: mysql

This is my table:

```
+------+--------+-------------------+
| user | item   | date_time         |
|   10 |     01 | 10-10-10 20:10:05 |
|   10 |     02 | 10-10-10 20:10:10 |
|   10 |     03 | 10-10-10 20:10:10 |
|   20 |     02 | 10-10-10 20:15:10 |
|   20 |     02 | 10-10-10 20:20:10 |
|   30 |     10 | 10-10-10 20:01:10 |
|   30 |     20 | 10-10-10 20:01:20 |
|   30 |     30 | 10-10-10 20:05:20 |
+------+--------+-------------------+
```

I want to do a query that return a user that took multiple items in a 1min interval, like this result:

```
+------+--------+-------------------+
| user | item   | date_time         |
|   10 |     01 | 10-10-10 20:10:05 |
|   10 |     02 | 10-10-10 20:10:10 |
|   10 |     03 | 10-10-10 20:10:10 |
|   30 |     10 | 10-10-10 20:01:10 |
|   30 |     20 | 10-10-10 20:01:20 |
+------+--------+-------------------+
```

How can I do this?

---

#### Edit

And if I want to only display users that appear 2 or more times on this output?

Example:

```
+------+--------+-------------------+
| user | item   | date_time         |
|   10 |     01 | 10-10-10 20:10:05 |
|   10 |     02 | 10-10-10 20:10:10 |
|   10 |     03 | 10-10-10 20:10:10 |
+------+--------+-------------------+
```

Comment: +1 on this question for providing good test data & expected results.

Comment: can you have same user, item and date_time or you can count that date_time is unique for user and item combination?

Comment: one user never get two items or more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to add a primary key (id) as suggested by @Will.

To get each item once (and only once) regardless of how many matches there were within the 1-minute window, try a subquery instead of a full join:

```
Select user,item,date_time from my_table t1
  where id in (select t2.id from my_table t2,my_table t3
      where t2.id <> t3.id and t2.user = t3.user 
           and abs(t2.date_time - t3.date_time) < 60)
```

--edit--
For your edited question, that depends on exactly what you mean. Do you mean "users who bought 3 or more items within 60 seconds" or "users who appear more than 2 times in the output". The latter is easy to do: assume the results of the above query are saved in a temporary table (or view) "temp1":

```
select * from my_table where user in 
    (select user from temp1 group by user having count(*) > 2);
```

Comment: very very nice ! this work well !
but, now i need this result only appear users that have 2 or more itens in this condition, output example:

-------------------------------------
| user | item   | date_time         |
|   10 |     01 | 10-10-10 20:10:05 |
|   10 |     02 | 10-10-10 20:10:10 |
|   10 |     03 | 10-10-10 20:10:10 |
-------------------------------------

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to join the table against itself (let's call the table aliases T1 and T2).  Then write a WHERE clause to filter only rows where T1.user is equal T2.user and the absolute value of the difference between T1.date_time and T2.date_time is less than a minute.

But the problem is that every row will get selected, because you have no primary key on your table, thus there's no way to detect when a row is getting joined with itself.  Create a primary key (an autonumber sequence will work just fine), and add a condition to the WHERE clause that says `T1.id <> T2.id`.

So in (untested) code form:

```
SELECT *
FROM stuff T1, stuff T2
WHERE T1.user = T2.user
  AND ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(T1.date_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(T2.date_time)) < 60
  AND T1.id <> T2.id;
```

Comment: This returns too many rows when the user buys more than 2 items within the 1-minute window. On the sample data given, it returns 8 rows, not 5.

Answer (score 0):

let's try that one:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable  
JOIN (SELECT MAX(date_time) AS maxi, MIN(date_time) AS mini, user AS uid FROM myTable GROUP BY uid) AS otherTable  
ON date_time<=maxi AND date_time>=mini AND user = uid AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(maxi) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mini) < 60  
GROUP BY uid, date_time
```

Comment: The approach of selecting the max & min transaction times for each user and joining on maxi-mini > 60 doesn't work. Running this on the test data, it picks up transactions for user 20, and misses user 10.

Comment: @David: you're right I was wrong with the operator... I have edited my answer to change that

Comment: But that's not going to work either (try it with the sample data). You can't solve this by looking at just the max and min for a given user: for example, user 30 has 2 transactions within 1 minute, but max-min > 60.